# Top promise .catch not triggered when returned child promise rejects

Tags: javascript, promise

I have this:

```
function sayHello() {
    return new Promise( resolve => {
       throw new Error('reject');
    });
}

new Promise(resolve => sayHello()).then(ok => console.log('ok:', ok)).catch( err => console.error('err:', err) );
```

However the `.catch` never triggers. I though if I return a promise within a promise, it gets chained so that top level `.then` and `.catch` are re-reouted to child `.then` and `.catch`?

Comment: Hey `Promise Based functions should not throw Exceptions`. SO what you are trying to do is fundamentally wrong. Please read this on how to handle these in different ways http://www.2ality.com/2016/03/promise-rejections-vs-exceptions.html

Comment: You are never resolving the promise on which you chain onto.

Comment: @Panther It's fine to `throw` inside promise callbacks, as those exceptions will automatically lead to a rejection

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<strike>The problem is with your "new error" thrown at the Promise callback. Throwing an error inside promise executor does not automatically reject it.</strike>
**Edit:** actually Promise executor **does automatically reject** the promise when an exception is thrown. Nevertheless, this is not the main cause of your problem. Also a note - throwing will only work on the "main" level of executor, so any asynchronous job throwing an exception won't automatically reject the promise.

Another problem spotted - your Promise chain (`new Promise(resolve => sayHello())...`) is also invalid - you are simply returning a function call result. You **always** have to manually resolve or reject a Promise that you've created with it's standard constructor (aka. `new Promise(executorCallback)`).

To fix the other problem, you can use "automatically resolved promise", which I think will do what you are trying to achieve:

```
Promise.resolve(sayHello()).then(...)
```

So in the end, your code should look like this (using [the gist](https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/768b78c07a9af333a42ff1bc774ba72a) you have posted in the comment below by answer):

```
function sayHello() {
    return new Promise( (resolve,reject) => {
       reject('rawr')
    });
}

Promise.resolve(sayHello()).then(ok => console.log('ok:', ok)).catch( err => console.error('err:', err) );
```

Comment: Thank you mdziekon for your comment! I tried to use `reject` inside `sayHello` like this, however it still didn't work - https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/768b78c07a9af333a42ff1bc774ba72a

Comment: Yup, because there is another problem with your code. Look at my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for that catch! Let me double check that typo is not in my test code and report back. :)

Comment: I've posted a final code (fixed your gist) that works.

Comment: Oh wow thank you! Even a `throw` instead of a `reject` in `sayHello` of your code causes top level `.catch` to trigger. Superb! Thank you!

Comment: Yea... actually it turned out I was wrong about that part with throwing an exception in the executor (I've re-read the documentation again). I've made an amendment for anyone who might read this answer in the future.